# No response from servlet unless it is in debugging mode

Tags: java, http, servlets, java-io

I have a servlet which sends string(url-link) to the client. In normal mode I always receive null, but when debugging and executing all commands step by step "manually" I get the correct response.

What might be the reason? It seems that I am not good at servlets as I don't have any logical assumptions.

Comment: Is the behaviour the same when using another servlet container?  Jetty is a good choice.

Comment: AppEngine is used whose servlet container is Jetty.

Comment: Then try Tomcat, or Winstone or any other container listed on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container#List_of_Servlet_containers

Comment: Are you manually creating `Thread` or `Runnable` instances which are dealing with submitted data? You should not do that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have a timing issue.  Is the value dependent upon another request from the client, or is it being updated by a different thread on the server?

Comment: Client sends request just once and waits for the response. There is no other thread created manually - just servlet.

Comment: This sounds like a fairly simple use-case.  Can you post the servlet and also the client-side code that's calling it?